# Limiting number of each item in knapsack solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying to better understand knapsack problems and am looking at the "Specific Dynamic Programming solution" given here:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_Problem/Python

I want to modify it so at most one of each item in items can be used in the solution. I thought this could be done by looping through items outside of weight and volume, but this did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Example:
Currently the code defines an items list

```
items = [Bounty('panacea', 3000,   3,  25),
         Bounty('ichor',   1800,   2,  15),
         Bounty('gold',    2500,  20,   2)]
```

it chooses the maximum value combo of items that is < the weight and volume limits of the knapsack and allows each item to be used multiple times.

I want it to choose the maximum value combo of items that has a weight and value < the weight and volume limits of the knapsack, but with the constraint that each item in items can be used a maximum of one time.

Comment: Show us what you have so far, and what's not working?

Comment: @SamSegers I am working with exactly what is listed under "Specific Dynamic Programming solution" at that link. Right now it returns               "The maximum value achievable (by dynamic programming) is 54500
  The number of panacea,ichor,gold items to achieve this is: [9, 0, 11], respectively"  However, I would like it to only allow at most 1 of each item to be used. I plan to be working from a list of many more items, but a list where there is only one unit available of each item.

Comment: I suppose you mean that you want to return the best item type as output? Add an example for understanding for the reader.

Comment: @SamSegers I edited the original post.

Comment: You can try a well known algorithm working in O(n * W) where n is the number of items and W is the capacity of the knapsack. Let me know if you want a detailed answer on this.

Comment: @pkacprzak I think this may be what I am looking for. Basically I want the multiple constraints functionality of the solution in the link I posted to be coupled with a 0/1 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent that each item is used multiple times:

#### 1) Make the DP algorithm decreasing instead of increasing + process this per item first instead of looping over weigth and volume first

In this way each item can't be counted multiple times more than once.

And by looping over the items first you don't take the chance of missing combinations of items.

As an example when your table is empty and you process your first item. It will take the best of the current and the best at position `[w-weight][v-volume]+value`

```
table[w][v] = max(table[w][v], table[w - item.weight][v - item.volume] + item.value)
```

So for *panacea*:

- When you are going in increasing order `table[25][3]` will be `3000` when processing `table[50][6]`. Making it 6000, using it 2 times.
- When you are going in decreasing order `table[25][3]` will still be `0` when processing `table[50][6]`. Making it 3000, only using it once.

So whatever will be in a lower table value, it won't be from the same item.

#### 2) Check when all items fit the knapsack

By the way this is implemented this indeed crashes when all items fit the knapsack.

You can rewrite this or simply add a check at the beginning of the method:

```
def knapsack_dp(items, sack):
    if(sum(item.weight for item in items) <= sack.weight
        and sum(item.volume for item in items) <= sack.volume):
        return [1] * len(items)
```

When it fully fits, return all items.

[Running example](http://ideone.com/FgrHzZ)

Comment: Thanks,                                                                                     for w in reversed(xrange(sack.weight + 1)):
        for v in reversed(xrange(sack.volume + 1)): gives an out of bounds error and reversing and removing the + 1 yields an empty sack. Perhaps you could explain the logic behind this idea more?

Comment: I hope my explanation helps you understanding why this works.

Comment: I think I follow your logic but as I said in the comment using reversed yields an error.

Comment: All the magic happens in the table matrix. Which in fact is doing the actual DP. Try to debug or print out the table after iterating over each item.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can use `O(n * W)` dynamic programming approach, where `n` is the number of items and `W` is the capacity of the knapsack. For more details please refer here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem

The algorithm is very easy to implement and quite fast if only `W` is small enough.

Comment: I understand and have implemented this. However, I am having trouble limiting by multiple constraints ie as the link in the OP does with volume in addition to weight.

Comment: Could you try to explain what you miss in more details? It seems that you want to decide if it's better to take an item or not and the above algorithm does this exactly. At the beginning you can throw out additional items, so that at most 1 item of each kind is remaining. Does it make any sense?

Comment: This approach is limiting the number of distinct items, and in my understanding @sfenske can have any number of distinct items, as long there is only 1 per type. Which is a different problem.